# Why does what gets pasted into contenteditable change when the div is created in javascript?

Tags: internet-explorer, contenteditable, paste

code: http://jsbin.com/mewixajito/2/edit?html,js,console,output

I'm trying to paste rich text/html (from say a website/google docs/word). So in the example, copy some rich text (say something bold or that has color) into the output of jsbin for `dynamic = true` and `dynamic = false` and see the difference.

If you change dynamic to true, then the pasted content won't have the correct styling and basically becomes plaintext.

`"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry"`

If dynamic is false (use the contenteditable from the html), then the content pasted is:

`"<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-e65c220d-7af8-1058-1ff7-d7af0ef00ef9\" style='color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-family: \"Courier New\"; font-size: 11px; font-style: italic; font-variant: normal; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry</span><br>"`

I would like to keep the styled pasted content but create the div dynamically. Maybe I'm creating it in the wrong way?

Comment: add a class on the fly instead of styling

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? I edited the question a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was because it was using `document.documentElement` instead of just plain `document.body`!